# How can I add CData as a XElement Value in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, cdata

I've got a PS script that creates some XML and assigns values to the XElements.  I need the value of the  XElement to be wrapped in CData.  This is using System.Xml.Linq
I tried this:

```
$newNode.Element("details").Value = '<![CDATA[Traceback:'+$_.Exception.toString()+']]>'
```

but when I output the xml, it converts the '<' and '>' to &lt and &gt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an object of type `XCData` to your element

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.Linq") | Out-Null

[System.Xml.Linq.XCData] $cdata = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.Linq.XCdata -ArgumentList "data"
[System.Xml.Linq.XElement] $element = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.Linq.XElement -ArgumentList "test", $cdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$cdata = $xml.CreateCDataSection($content)
$parent = $xml.GetElementsByTagName("TagName")[0]
$parent.AppendChild($cdata)
```

Comment: Your answer is based on xmlDocument, I'm looking for a solution based on XDocument. (System.Xml.Linq)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer because google keeps redirecting here and Shay Levy's answer did not quite work for me. Note that this won't answer the original question.

To add a new element with a CDATA section to an `XmlElement` object, both the new element and then its `CDATA` element must be added to the root xml doc, before they can be assigned to the node of interest.

```
$xmlRoot # your xml root doc here
$xmlNode # the node in question

$newXmlElement = xmlNode.AppendChild($xmlRoot.CreateElement("newXmlElement"))            
$newXmlElement.AppendChild($xmlRoot.CreateCDataSection("your value here"))

# The following will be appended to the content of xmlNode:
# <newXmlElement><![CDATA[your value here]]><newXmlElement>
```